# Docker container file permissions

Tags: docker, image, dockerfile, containers

I have a java application that saves a CSV file to the root folder of the application. I am trying to create a docker image of this and run it as a container. However, I want a non-root user with ID of 1010 to be able to access this file and not root. I get errors when trying to specify USER 1010 in my dockerfile

```sh
FROM adoptjdk (placeholder)
COPY ./myapp.jar /app/
USER 1010
WORKDIR /opt
EXPOSE PORTNO
```

That's just the basics of the dockerfile, essentially I want user 1010 to be able to access the CSV file that my java application creates. I am not sure where it saves my CSV file when it is run through docker.

Comment: You should probably save the data somewhere other than the container's `/`.  You will be forced to be the root user to read or write there, and you'll have trouble mounting external storage to that directory.  In the same way you have a `/app` directory, a `/data` container directory is easy and straightforward.

Comment: Do you mean to use a mkdir command to create a new folder called data and then point my WORKDIR to /data?

Comment: However you tell the application where to write its data, it shouldn't be directly in `/`.  `RUN mkdir /data` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your application shall write to / inside the container, and your application shall be running as user id 1010, then just set the filesystem privileges accordingly. I chime in that it may not be the recommended setup, but it is not impossible.

So put in your Dockerfile lines like

```
RUN chmod 777 /
```

or to be a bit smoother check the GID of / with

```
RUN ls -ln /
RUN chmod 775 /
```

then ensure your java application runs with uid 1010 and the GID you saw from the filesystem. In short, such things are the same, be it inside the container or outside.